# fastcgi++: Client sent unknown content type

Tags: fastcgi++

Have written simple server using fastcgi++ 2.1 lib and configured fastscgi in apache2 web server. When I make post request to the server with Content Type: application/json, server throws an internal server error. Have checked apache error.log file and found following log:

[Wed Jan 08 13:56:40 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] FastCGI: server "/var/www/testserver" stderr: "Client sent unknown content type." from "http://abcd.com/testserver" with a POST request method.

When I set Content Type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" its working fine and request get served. Please help me on how to serve request with Content Type as "application/json". Is there any configuration required for this to support?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah solved !

In fastcgi++ lib, Content Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is hard-coded. Have changed it to "application/json" and rebuild the fastcgi++ lib. Now I'm able to serve request with Content Type "application/json".

Comment: It's hardcoded in 2.1 release, but can be overridden in master branch, see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/fastcgipp.git/commit/?id=0ec3e7fb0f8f69e1d3b3e88e58862f7a1e5e9ff5